# Check if <li> exists in <ul> and don't show ajax content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have this function with Jquery Ajax:

```
$(function() {    
  setInterval(function(){ 
$.ajax({
//ajax code
 success: function(datax){
    $( "#messages" ).append(datax);
 },
//ajax code
});
  }, 1000);
});
```

The output is:

```
<li>123</li>
```

And a exactly the same `<li>` is in the following code:

```
<ul id="messages">
  <li>123</li>
</ul>
```

How to don't show if `<li>` exists?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this `ul` the `#messages` or a separate spot in the DOM? If it is separate do you want it just not show if it's in that `ul` specifically, or don't show if it exist anywhere in the DOM?

Comment: and what does datax look like?

Comment: I didn't put the ID in the <ul>. Fixed!
The output is in the question!

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {    
    setInterval(function(){ 
        // ajax code
        $('#messages li').is(':visible') ? $('#messages').hide() : $('#messages').show()
    }, 1000);
});
```

You might want to take a look into [datalists](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) as well.